# design pattern to use utility app connecting to internet

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, design-patterns

This may be a generic question but still i need suggestion/guidance on which design pattern or architecture to follow for developing this app.

The app is for premium users(for iPhone) on airport and will be able to access the internet at higher speed and on multiple devices simultaneously. 
I'm planning to go for Singleton,Factory,MVC patterns and client-server architecture for the app.
What-all things do i need to re-think and then design the app or are above patterns sufficient to go ahead ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems bizarre to come up with a list of patterns to use before you look at what your app is actually going to do. This is not how you use design patterns.

The way to use patterns: When you have a problem, and you think about how to solve it, you try to find out whether your problem fits a well-known pattern and adapt that pattern to your problem. Or you figure out that it doesn't fit any well-known pattern, and then you solve the problem without using any pattern.

This is like going to a shop buying blue and yellow paint, and then deciding what parts of your home you want to paint. You do it the other way round. You decide what needs painting, then you decide what would be a nice colour, then you buy the colour. You don't buy the paint first. You don't decide on design patterns first.

Comment: i completely agree with you and really appreciate for clearing my confusion on way i'm designing the app. But how do i start designing my app based on the requirements.